# How to output a custom static file in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

Using Sphinx, one can include static files in the _static folder of the build output. How could I copy a static file to the root of the build folder?

Background: I'm hosting the output of a Sphinx project in Azure App Services, and because of a mp4 video in a few pages, I need a "web.config" file with the following entry:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

I need Sphinx to include the web.config in the root of the build folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`html_extra_path`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_extra_path). This is a configuration option that will copy the list of files given to the html build directory:

```
html_extra_path = ['path/to/web.config']
```